# Modal shows the content of html instead of its own content

Tags: php, html, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I don't get why the modal is showing my html's body content when I submit an input instead of the result of php.

I tried debugging it,then i found out that the modal shows its own content when I add data-toggle and data-target to the input/form, but the problem is that the modal shows after I click on the input even before I can even type something,and even I managed to type something, the same problem still exists

Here's the form:

```
<form id="form_id" action="some_php.php" method="POST">
    <input id="input_id" type="text" name="input_name">
</form>
```

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form_id").submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("form_id").serialize(),
            url: 'some_php.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#fetched-data").html(data);
                $("#myModal").show('show');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Show all the code ... This much works ok.

Comment: Sorry,I managed to solved this, the culprit is the redirect I put as protection for the some_php.php

Comment: @T.Shah Should I delete this post? Or is there something that can be clicked to marked this as solved?